# Forward converter with RCD clamp

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

In case of a Flyback converter, the RCD clamp is supposed to dissipate only the energy stored in the leakage inductance. However, in case of a Forward converter it would dissipate the energy from the magnetizing inductance (and by that resetting the core). But isn't that power dissipation so much that it makes it unacceptable?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure RCD is the term you want here. Or if it is, I'm much less familiar with DC-DC converters than I'd thought.

Comment: Sounds like a snubber to me. Capacitor charged through diode, discharged through resistor.

Comment: I think you really do need to post a schematic for this. And, I think you are assuming that the mag inductance plays a relevant role in a forward converter when it doesn't that much.

Comment: Once you have a considerable amount of current built up in \$L_1\$, during the off-state of \$Q_1\$, \$D_1\$ is conducting. Any remaining magnetizing current in the core will fade out (or not) through \$D_5\$ and \$D_1\$, but first through \$D_2\$ until \$U_{C_1}\$ reaches the level that \$D_5\$ opens (corrected for turns ratio). After that it's indeed only the magnetizing current of the primary leakage inductance that continues through \$D_2\$ and \$C_1\$. So, no, there won't be excessive dissipation in \$R_1\$, unless \$D_1\$ doesn't freewheel at all. Hmm, let me consider if it's an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In case of a Flyback converter, the RCD clamp is supposed to dissipate
>   only the energy stored in the leakage inductance.

Correct.

> However, in case of a Forward converter it would dissipate the energy
>   from the magnetizing inductance

Also correct but, there is more than an order of magnitude difference between the energy exclusively stored in the primary of the flyback transformer (for use with the secondary) AND the very much smaller level of energy stored in the magnetization inductance of a forward converter. There are many more primary turns comparing apples with apples.

For a forward converter, in the first part of its switching cycle, conventional transformer operation occurs and the primary current is "mainly" the load current from the secondary (referred to the primary via the turns ratio). The actual primary "load" current is very much greater than the magnetization current and hence, when the 2nd part of the switching cycle commences, there is a very much smaller amount of energy to dissipate than that transferred through to the secondary.

That amount of energy is similar to the amount of energy needed to be got-rid-of in a conventional flyback converter due to leakage inductance. The forward converter does this by having about 4 times the number of primary/secondary turns compared to a flyback transformer. 4 times the turns means 16 times the inductance and, for the same switching frequency and primary DC voltage, the magnetization current is 16 times smaller.

> But isn't that power dissipation so much that it makes it
>   unacceptable?

This means that the primary magnetization energy is one-sixteenth of that for the equivalent flyback transformer i.e. not in the same ballpark.

Of course, some flyback transformers will run with less than 4 times the turns than the equivalent flyback transformer but, the general trend is that the forward converter uses several times the number of primary turns compared to the flyback transformer.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. The main source of confusion was that many designs use active clamp Forward topology, which aims for soft switching by lowering the primary inductance to about 100uH. And if I would like to use the RCD clamp on of these transformers designed for active clamp, then the dissipation would be high. But as you said, the classic Forward transformer has much higher primary inductance and thus lower magnetizing current, which means the RCD clamp can be used. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a considerable amount of current built up in \$L_1\$, during the off-state of \$Q_1\$ \$D_1\$ will be conducting. Any remaining magnetizing current in the core will fade out through \$D_5\$ and \$D_1\$, but first through \$D_2\$ until \$U_{C_1}\$ reaches the level that \$D_5\$ opens (corrected for turns ratio). After that it's indeed only the magnetizing current of the primary leakage inductance that continues through \$D_2\$ and \$C_1\$. So, no, there won't be excessive dissipation in \$R_1\$, unless \$D_1\$ doesn't freewheel at all.

Comment: Why would \$D_5\$ open during the off-state of Q1?

Comment: D5 and D1 can never conduct at the same time so how can any current pass through both simultaneously?

Comment: If \$C_1\$ is sufficiently small its voltage multiplied by \$N_p/N_s\$ will rise fast enough for the magnetizing current to choose the secondary, \$D_5\$ and the still conducting \$D_1\$ to flow through, as this is the path then with the lowest voltage. But when the magnetizing current in the secondary winding is larger than the remaining current through \$L_1\$, it will force \$D_1\$ to close and will choose between \$D_2\$ and \$D_5\$, whichever gives the lowest voltage to dump itself into.

Comment: Aye, you both are right, I got the polarity of the magnetizing current wrong. Shall I delete my answer and comments?